# mtp-detect doesn't detect my Sony Ericsson phone

Tags: arch-linux, usb, mtp

I used to have a Samsung Galaxy Fit that worked out of the box with Banshee.

I recently bought a new Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini, I tried to sync it using Banshee, but it doesn't show up.

It does mount when I switch to Mass Storage mode, and I can see it using `lsusb` but running `mtp-detect` outputs `No raw devices found.`

I'm running Gnome 3 on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [libmtp homepage](http://libmtp.sourceforge.net/) (the source of `mtp-detect`):

> If you happen upon a device which libmtp claims it cannot autodetect,
>   please:
>
> - Submit the vendor ID and device ID as a bug, patch or feature request on the [Sourceforge bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=158745&atid=809061) at our homepage.
> - If it gives a sensible output from "mtp-detect" then please attach the result as well as it teaches us some stuff about your device.
> - If it doesn't give sensible output, attach the output from "lsusb -v" for your device.
> - If you want to be able to hack some more and you're not afraid of C hacking, add an entry for your device's vendor/product ID and a
>     descriptive string to the database in the file [src/music-players.h](http://libmtp.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=libmtp/libmtp;a=blob;f=src/music-players.h;hb=HEAD).
> - If you want to poke around to see if your device has some special peculiarities, you can test some special device flags defined in
>     [src/device-flags.h](http://libmtp.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=libmtp/libmtp;a=blob;f=src/device-flags.h;hb=HEAD) by inserting them together with your device entry
>     in src/music-players.h. Flags can be tested in isolation or catenated
>     with "|" (binary OR). If relatives to your device use a certain flag,
>     chances are high that a new device will need it too, typically from
>     the same manufacturer. The most common flag that needs to be set is
>     the DEVICE_FLAG_UNLOAD_DRIVER that detach any Linux kernel drivers
>     that may have attached to the device making MTP access impossible.

Comment: I'll try and do that, but it's not an mtp problem, it also doesn't show up when I use it as removable storage.